# Use tmux for managing multiple downloaders as a supervisorctl service?

Tags: bash, service, wget, tmux, supervisord

I have many data-servers I need to download data from via http as soon as it is available. For each server I start a `bash` "`while true`"-loop and within that a `wget` to poll the server for new data. To start all the `bash`s I created a `tmux` config starting a window for every loop such loop and `wget`. This adds the benefit of easier inspecting what is happening.

I want to create a `supervisor`-service from this config, which would allow me to start, stop, and restart this `tmux` and its downloading clients all at once.

However, when I quit `tmux`, by the very nature of `tmux`, the `bash`s and their `wget`s keep running. Is there a way around that, so I can quit everything and restart everything with a simple `supvervisorctl tmuxservice restart`?

Comment: how did you **quit** your tmux?

Comment: I let supervisor do it